# DateTime2 error when I'm not using DateTime2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I'm getting this error when I run my create action on my controller :The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value"

Here is my Domain class:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public DateTime DateAdded {get; set;}
}
```

In the controller "POST" create actions I have this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyEntity entity)
{
     entity.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
     entity.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
     // the name will be added from the view
     db.MyContext.Add(entity);
     db.Save(); 
}
```

I'm not sure where the datatime2 is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework, when modeling a SQL Server database, *considers* all date fields of type `DateTime2`.

So if, in your SQL Server database, a field is actually defined as a `DateTime`, you would get an out of range issue when you leave a date empty or when you specify another value that is in-range for `DateTime2` but out of range for `DateTime`. Entity Framework itself doesn't catch this problem because it just assumes `DateTime2`.

The solution is to check that you have filled in values for all date fields and that they are within range.

Comment: Thanks, but I checked the column in the database and its DateTime but I fixed the error.

Comment: Yes, if the column in the DB is of type DateTime, then this problem can occur, because Entity Framework considers all dates to be of type DateTime2. If the column type is DateTime2, no error should occur.

Comment: My answer above solved the problem without having to change any types in the model or database

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this. I forgot/over looked I had an "DateChange" field

This now works

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public DateTime DateAdded {get; set;}
    public DateTime DateChanged {get; set;}
}
```

In the controller "POST" create actions I have this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyEntity entity)
{
     entity.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
     entity.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
     entity.DateChanged = DateTime.Now;
     // the name will be added from the view
     db.MyContext.Add(entity);
     db.Save(); 
}
```

Still not sure why it give the conversion of a datetime2 error for.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer: "The solution is to **check that you have filled in values for all date fields**..."